# Java Jackson Deserialization - Custom add to list

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a question regarding how Jackson deserializes a List.

I searched online before writing this question but I didn't find anything (probably I didn't find anything because in reality I wouldn't know exactly what to look for)...

I have this json

```json
{
    "list": [
        {"name": "Paul"},
        {"name": "Charles"}
    ]
}
```

and I have this classes

```java
public class OuterClass {
    private List<InnerClass> list;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

```java
public class InnerClass {
    private int prog;
    private String name;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I can deserialize the json with the statement

```java
OuterClass outerClass = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, OuterClass.class);
```

achieving this result

```
OuterClass [list=[InnerClass [prog=0, name=Paul], InnerClass [prog=0, name=Charles]]]
```

Obviously the `prog` property of the `InnerClass` class is not valued (since it is not present in the json). What I would need is, in some way, to set `prog` with a progressive. That is, get this

```
OuterClass [list=[InnerClass [prog=1, name=Paul], InnerClass [prog=2, name=Charles]]]
```

Thanks in advance